# Show that $G$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $F$ be a field. Let $G=\{x^2\mid x\in F^\ast \}$. Show that $G$ is a group.

---

Since $F^\ast$ is a field with non zero elements, then there exists an identity $e$ in $F^\ast$ such that $e^2=ee=e\in G$, so $G$ is not empty. Let $a,b\in G$, then $a=x^2, b=y^2$ where $x,y$ are non zero elements in $F$. Then $b^{-1}=(y^2)^{-1}=(y^{-1})^2$, so $ab^{-1}=x^2(y^{-1})^2=(xy^{-1})^2\in G$. By the one step subgroup test, $G$ is a group.

---

Does the argument above right? If not, can someone give me a suggestion to write a better proof? Thanks

Comment: looks correct..

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is correct. The following is an alternative, but not necessarily better proof:

> $G$ is the image of the group homomorphism $F^\times \to F^\times$, $x\mapsto x^2$.

(And of course it is only so concise because it leaves out showing that this is s homomorphism in the first place)